# How to get the state from Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, states

So i was creating the Redux store in the `app.js` file. I also pushing many data from the database to the initial state of the  Redux store.

Now I am creating a plain js file ( not React class ). Now i was confused how to get the state of the store in this file.

If this is a React class , I can use the function `mapStateToProps` to map the redux state to the class props, But this is just a js file with functions , i dont want to create a whole React class for this.

Is there any ways??

Comment: Import your `store` object and do `store.getState()`?

Comment: @Li357 do i have to export the store somewhere first ? i cannot seem to import it

Comment: Yes, that would be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the store in a separate file , if you're using [ES Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/) export it , now in any file in your project you can import it and use it

`import store from './store'` if you use **export default** if you just export it use

`import {store}from './store'`

now you can use the store methods and functions

[store.getState()](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#getState) this you'll return your app state

[store.dispatch()](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#dispatch) to dispatch and action

you can discover other methods in the [redux apis page](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store)